# Attaching evenhandler to Icon created deep inside in controller

Tags: jquery, sapui5

I have a factory function to populate rows in a table. For each row I create a ColumnListItem inside which I create an Icon for each cell. This works fine.

However I am not able to attach a "named" function to it. When I click on the Icon I get the error "Object doesn't support property or method 'call'".
Could anyone point me how to do this? I need a named function because I do not want to repeat the code for each Icon.

I guess the problem is because "this" of controller is not available deep inside. Am I right?

Below is my factory method  and eventhandler method in controller -

```
    populateItems1 : function(sId, oContext) {
            var row = new ColumnListItem(sId, {
                cells : [ new Icon({
                    src : {
                        path : "row>col",
                        formatter : function(value) {
                            switch (value) {
                                case "1":
                                    return "sap-icon://sys-cancel";
                                                            default:
                                    return "sap-icon://sys-help"; 
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    color : {
                        path : "row>col",
                        formatter : function(value) {
                            switch (value) {
                                case "1":
                                    return "Critical";
                                default:
                                    return "black";
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    size : "1.5em",
                    press: ".onIconPress"  // this does not work 
                }) ]
            });

            return row;
        },

onIconPress : function(oEvent) {
            console.log("Info : ");
        }
```

Cheers,
Shailesh

Answer (score 0):

I could fix it myself. I posted it too early before trying something very obvious and basic:

```
press: [this.onIconPress]
```

I was attaching it incorrectly.